# Template reference error in meteor even if Template is already defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I am getting this error even if I already defined template in my html, I am missing something.
[Error in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7WWM.png)

index.html

```
<template name="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TextCircle</a>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li>
            <a href="#" class="js-add-doc">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              new Document
            </a>
         </li>

       </ul>
       <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">{{> loginButtons}}</p>
     </div>
   </nav>
</template>
```

main.js

```
Template.navbar.events({
     "click .js-add-doc":function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         console.log("add new doc");
      }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: where is your `main.js` file ?  it seems like it is loaded on the server side (or both server & client side).

Comment: my main.js is in the root folder, could that be the problem?

Comment: That resolved the issue, can you paste it as an answer so I  can mark as answer, incase someone else encounter the same problem

Comment: Per the error `TextCircle2.js` is your issue. This sounds like a template definition but it's being loaded on the server (it's in `server/app` folder). Make sure you follow the correct folder structure per the api(https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html)

Comment: @EmmanuelAmodu I posted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main.js` file is being loaded on the server side (or both server & client side) however `Template` is only available on the client side. For more information, please read [this](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure).
Also, since **Meteor 1.3** it is recommended to structure your app following [this example](https://github.com/meteor/todos).

Answer (score 0):

Try it or put your file into client folder in meteor structure.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.navbar.events({
     "click .js-add-doc":function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         console.log("add new doc");
      }
   });
}
```